Does a Raspberry Pi 5 needs the exact voltage for optimal functioning?
Question 1:
I'm planning to power a Raspberry Pi 5 with my old 33W mobile charger. I know that voltage rating is what that matters rather than ampere rating.
This is the rating of my mobile charger: 5-11V ~ 3A Max
My doubt is that will this damage my Raspberry Pi 5 by providing more volts?
Question 2:
I'm planning to build a NAS with Raspberry Pi 5 + 2 External HDD

Will there be any power issue if I connect them to Raspberry Pi 5?
Do I need an additional powered USB hub since the External HDD is not
having any external power supply?


https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements

@Milliways: Thanks. Can you help me with the Question 1?

You have not specified what your hardware requires but unless using the official supply it is doubtful that it will work, and even then 2 HDD is unlikely.


My doubt is that will this damage my Raspberry Pi 5 by providing more volts?

USB C chargers have a protocol for negotiating voltage that the Pi 5 uses, so it should be fine.
However, keep in mind chargers are not necessarily designed for providing power to electronic devices without a battery, and hence may under perform in terms of their ability to deliver instantaneous current when required in that context.  This issue may be compounded with the fact that it does not deliver the recommended 5A current.
The result of that is actually under voltage because that's part of what happens when you try to draw too much current from a power supply (the voltage will fluctuate).  It should not cause actual physical damage but it can cause, eg., data loss due to filesystem corruption.

goldilocks: So is it because the official Pi charger is a PD charger?

The official power supply is not a charger (although it could be used as one).  Part of the point here is that these are in fact not synonyms (by analogy, a car and a van are both vehicles and might both be fine for some particular purpose, but there are also some significant technical differences).  Anyway, yes it has power delivery (usually if you dig around a few ads or look on the official site you can find this kind of info),
